# What kind of Android menu is this?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is this menu standard, or is it custom? I would like to use/create a menu like this which has a grabber button when closed, and is used to drag open the menu, similar to a Navigation Draw. I found this application 'Smart Peel' which utilizes this idea. Below are screen shots.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZQSC.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiR2P.png

Comment: What kind of hardware is that running on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note GT-N5110. Thanks for the down vote, I wouldn't have asked if I hadn't done plenty of searching.

Comment: Oh I got confused by the power button, I thought you were running something weird but I guess it's a remote controller app. Also IDK who downvoted u don't take it personal.

Comment: No problem. (on DV)It's not personal, it just seems like people abuse the hell out of it. And then they hide and give no reason. You can't improve something if you don't know whats wrong. It should require a comment to down vote.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably custom, you can find tons of Android UI/UX Libraries on [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui), the libraries were open sourced where you can use and implement them into your own application.

Comment: Thank you for that link, Awesome resource, perfect for learning too.